# How could Kowalski remember what happened in New York? And is the movie explanation?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Whoever saw the trailer is able to see that Kowalski plays a major role in the *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*.

> But at the end of the end of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, every Muggle was obliviated. So how does it come, that he remembers what happened?

In Fantatic Beasts II there was one explanation for it:

> According to Kowalski, he could remember everything, because the magic Newt did only erased bad memories. So he kept most of his memories - and Queenie Goldstein helped with the rest of the memories. But I don't buy it. At the end of Fantastic Beasts I, he couldn't remember Queenie at all - he only had some weird memories and baked weird bread. Is that a plothole?

Comment: Explained in my answer to the dupe. Although he has the memories, they had a dreamlike quality

Comment: @Valorum please link to your answer

Comment: Hi, the dupe question is [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150367/what-happened-at-the-end-of-fantastic-beasts-with-queenie-and-jacob) and my answer is the second one down.