# Why did it take so long for Jacob to recover his supposedly happy memories?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In "The Crimes of Grindelwald" it answers [why Jacob recovered his memories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150367/what-happened-at-the-end-of-fantastic-beasts-with-queenie-and-jacob):

> NEWT: But you were supposed to have been Obliviated!
>
> JACOB: I know!
>
> NEWT: So . . . But . . .
>
> JACOB: It didn’t work, pal. I mean, you said it, the potion only erases bad memories. I didn’t have any. I mean, don’t get me wrong, I had some weird ones. But this angel . . . this angel over here, she filled me in on all the bad parts, and here we are, I guess, huh?

But why did Jacob seemingly forget Queenie until they were reintroduced? If it's completely true that the potion only erases bad memories, why would he be confused at the end of the first Fantastic Beasts? He should have immediately remembered Queenie?

Comment: I've voted to close as a dupe. I could pretty much copy my answer from there over to here.

Comment: @Valorum WHAT??? How exactly is this a dupe? This is clearly a new question.

Comment: My answer to that question entirely answers this one. The potion gave his memories a dreamlike quality. He remembered, but the memories jarred with the false memory that the potion created. In the absence of any evidence to the contrary, he accepted the false memories. When Queenie turned up, he had evidence that the real memories were accurate and they came flooding back.

Comment: @Valorum The fact that your answer answers this one does NOT mean its a dupe. Furthermore, there may be other, more canonical answers.

Comment: I've previously been told, in Meta, that another question that only *answers* my question *does* constitute a duplicate

Comment: @Gnemlock - The general principle is that you can use answers from another question as a *benchmark* to determine whether two apparently dissimilar questions are actually duplicates. If you can port answers from one over to the other without any major changes and directly answer both, it's almost certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

He (sorta) remembered her, at least according to the film's official screenplay.

> The bell tinkles again.
>
> JACOB looks up and is thunderstruck all over again: it’s QUEENIE. They
>   stare at each other – QUEENIE beams, radiant. JACOB, quizzical and
>   totally enchanted, touches his neck – **a flicker of memory**. He smiles
>   back.
>
> <sub><sup>[**Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fantastic-Beasts-Where-Find-Them/dp/1408708981)</sup></sub>

And the actor seems pretty convinced that his memory was returned when he saw her.

> **Alison:** *It’s the best. So that actually brings us, though… If they’re having a complex relationship, does Jacob remember what happened* [in the] *last film? It’s kind of hinted at at the end, but it was never confirmed, so…*
>
> **Dan:** *I think he does have… yeah. It’s not explained exactly why, but he does have some recollection for sure, yeah.*
>
> **Alison:** *Okay. So there’s not a period where he has to relearn everything.*
>
> **Dan:** *Relearn everything! And he’s reading this scroll before…*
>
> [Alison and Cat laugh]
>
> **Dan:** *“Ahh, okay, I’m back* [unintelligible].” ***No, I think you see at the end of the first one. It comes flooding back to him***
>
> <sub><sup>[EXCLUSIVE: Dan Fogler Talks Queenie and Jacob and More in “Crimes of Grindelwald” at Comic-Con!](http://www.mugglenet.com/2018/07/exclusive-dan-fogler-talks-about-queenie-and-jacob-and-more-surprises-in-crimes-of-grindelwald-at-comic-con/)</sup></sub>

---

We also now have an update relating to Fantastic Beasts 2: The Crimes of Grindlewald. Evidently his memories of the Wizarding world were *confirmed* by Queenie's presence. Before that they were dreamlike.

> **Felicia Grady:** *What parts from the first film did Queenie have to catch Jacob up on? Did Jacob remember the Erumpent incident?*
>
> **Alison:** *That’s a good question.*
>
> **Felicia:** *Because he forgot all the bad memories.*
>
> **Dan:** *Yeah, I think he remembered a lot of it.*
>
> **Alison:** *Weren’t there Erumpent puffs?*
>
> **Dan:** *Erumpent puffs, Niffler muffins… It’s like Midsummer Night’s Dream. Have you ever seen Midsummer Night’s Dream, where Bottom wakes
>   up and he’s like, “I think I had a dream,” but he’s not sure? That’s
>   what I think happens to him. You guys all saw it. The poison, the
>   Thunderbird shower, the Obliviation spell… It erases bad memories and
>   he didn’t have any bad memories.*
>
> **Felicia:** *Even the Erumpent was a good memory?*
>
> **Dan:** *Even the Erumpent was a good memory, yes.*
>
> **Alison:** *She was good. She liked you so much.*
>
> **Dan:** *Exactly. He may not remember the scary parts of it, but he definitely remembers being in the case. And looking over it and he
>   just being like, “Hey?” It became familiar. So he retains it. Puts it
>   in his heart. It seeps into his art form with the muffins and
>   everything. And he had his Titania, his dream girl, and then she walks
>   into the bakery. I think he’s got the scar in his neck. I think that’s
>   the one thing where it’s like, “Where the hell did I get that crazy
>   scar in my neck?” Then it all comes flooding back when she’s smiling
>   at him. Or a lot of it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Alison Sudol and Dan Fogler “Crimes of Grindelwald” Roundtable Interview](http://www.mugglenet.com/2018/11/alison-sudol-and-dan-fogler-crimes-of-grindelwald-roundtable-interview/)</sup></sub>

This is confirmed in the dialogue for Fantastic Beasts 2

> **NEWT**: *But you were supposed to have been Obliviated!*
>
> **JACOB:** *I know!*
>
> **NEWT:** *So . . . But . . .*
>
> **JACOB:** *It didn’t work, pal. I mean, you said it, the potion only erases bad memories. I didn’t have any. I mean, don’t get me wrong, I had some weird ones. But this angel . . . this angel over here, she filled me in on all the bad parts, and here we are, I guess, huh?*
>
> <sub><sup>[Fantastic Beasts 2: Original Screenplay](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fantastic-Beasts-Grindelwald-Original-Screenplay/dp/1408711702)</sup></sub>